# Filling multiple divs with single ajax() call, form submit button fails

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

The short question is when I fill a `<div>` containing a `type=submit` button the `.click(function(){...}` function fails.

What I'm doing is this, `#formDialogButton` opens `#accordion` populated by `.ajax()` containing `#userForm` with an `input type=submit`. When client clicks submit it is supposed to fire `.ajax()` where php does database stuff and returns one of the `#userform`.

```
            $(".formDialogButton").click(function(){
            var userDialog = "#" + this.id + "Dialog";
            $("#userForm, #siteForm, #limitForm").html("<img src='ajax-loader.gif' />");
            $("#userForm, #siteForm, #limitForm").load("ajax.php", {op: "forms"}, function(responseTxt,statusTxt,xhr){
                $("#userForm").html($("#user").html());
                $("#siteForm").html($("#site").html());
                $("#limitForm").html($("#limit").html());
                if(statusTxt=="success") {
                    $(userDialog).dialog({
                        autoOpen: false,
                        draggable: true,
                        modal: true,
                        resizable: true,
                        width: 700,
                        position: { within: "#mainContent" }
                    });
                    $(userDialog).dialog("open");
                    $( "#accordion").accordion({ 
                        collapsible: true,
                        heightStyle: "content",
                    });
                };
                if(statusTxt =="error")
                    alert("Error: "+xhr.status+": "+xhr.statusText);
            });
        });
```

This is working and returns a `<input class="submitAndReturn" type="submit" value="Submit" />` in the form. But I can't "find" it to do anything.

```
            $(".submitAndReturn").click(function() {
        alert ('this is where I call my regular .formSubmitButton and let  success: function() do a .formDialogButton ');
        });
```

I'm a total self taught amateur so please forgive me and try to help. Thanks

Comment: _But I can't "find" it to do anything._ Where are you trying to "find" it?

Comment: By "find" it I mean my alert() isn't triggering

Comment: Where do you assign the click function to `$(".submitAndReturn")`? Does `$(".submitAndReturn")` live on the page or is it loaded dynamically by Ajax?

Comment: It lives in the .js included in the head of the page inside `$(document).ready(function(){}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like you are trying to add the click event before the element is loaded on the page. Change

```
$(".submitAndReturn").on("click", function() {
    alert ('as .submit and return is dynamically loaded. so, use on function');
});
```

to

```
$(document).on("click", ".submitAndReturn", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault(); //cancel the click action if needed
    alert ('as .submit and return is dynamically loaded. so, use on function');
});
```

Comment: No, tried that also. I've got alerts() inside every function I have and none of them are stopping the execution.

Comment: Did you prevent the default action of the buttons you clicked? If you set your debugger to not clear the console between page loads, do you see a JavaScript error?

Comment: If the second one does not work, something unstated is at work here.

Comment: woopie! All I did was look at it for awhile ?? after changing to `e.preventDefault()` and it nis now triggering `alert ('as .submit and return is dynamically loaded. so, use on function');`

Answer (score 0):

```
    $(".submitAndReturn").on("click", function() {
    alert ('as .submit and return is dynamically loaded. so, use on function');
    });
```

Comment: any problem can be discussed with me!

Comment: I've found that earlier and tried it but I'm still failing. The site reloads complete.

Comment: your site have other functions also? do they work? i think there is some syntax error then!

Answer (score 0):

> What I'm doing is this, #formDialogButton opens #accordion populated by .ajax() containing #userForm with an input type=submit

If I understand it correct `.formDialogButton` DOM element is getting loaded in `.ajax()` callback event.

If you are loading the javascript in question above in header or at the page end, most likely the `$(".formDialogButton").click(function()` event is not getting attached to DOM.

This happens because the script has already fired before the AJAX has fetched the required DOM to which event has to be attached. You would need to attach the event in `.ajax()` success callback. Something like

```
$.ajax({
  url: 'YOUR_URL_TO_FETCH_FORM',
  success: function(data) {
    // associate click
    $(".formDialogButton").click(function() // rest of the code
  }
});
```

Comment: If I understand you correctly then no, `.formDialogButton` exists on the page. When it is clicked ajax() is fired to get database form for the client to edit and submit with `.submitAndReturn`